# ondrop affects target's parent

Tags: javascript, html, parent, eventhandler

I've got one div in another div.
Both div have a ondrop property.
When I move an element in the child's dropzone, it calls the ondrop function twice. One time for the child and then one more for the parent.

My problem is : Even if the drop target is in another drop-target container, I don't want the container to be affected by the dropped element. In other words, I don't want the ondrop event to be fired twice.

Can you help me ?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Can you share some of your code? html/javascript? Are you using vanilla javascript? jquery? some other library?

Comment: we can't help you if you don't show us ur code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop event propagation E.g.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

This will stop the propagation of `drop` event to parent elements.

P.S. Some code won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using jQuery - you should use the `greedy` option of the `droppable` object:

```js
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  greedy: true,
  drop: function(e) {
    alert( "dropped inner" );
  }
});
$( "#droppable-big" ).droppable({
  greedy: true,
  drop: function(e) {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
#droppable-big {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 60px;
}
#droppable {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
<div id="droppable-big">
  <div id="droppable">Drop here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wasn't aware of that greedy attribute. Thank you !